# Changing nav-bar color on page loads ionic

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi i want to change the color of my `nav-bar` on every page load so i tried this :
 in the menu.html :

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">

<ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-nav-bar class="{{headerClass}}">

        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">

            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>

        </ion-nav-buttons>

    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view name="side-menu21"></ion-nav-view>

</ion-side-menu-content>

<ion-side-menu side="left">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">

        <div class="title">Menu</div>

    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content padding="false" class="side-menu-left has-header">

        <ion-list>

            <ion-item ui-sref="menu.home" menu-close="" class="item-icon-left"><i class="icon ion-home assertive"></i>Persée</ion-item>

            <ion-item ui-sref="menu.offreSFR" menu-close="" class="item-icon-left"><i class="icon ion-ios-cart royal"></i>Offres SFR</ion-item>

            <ion-item ui-sref="menu.mediatheque" menu-close="" class="item-icon-left"><i class="icon ion-ios-book energized"></i>Mediatheque</ion-item>

            <ion-item ui-sref="menu.reporting" menu-close="" class="item-icon-left"><i class="icon ion-stats-bars balanced"></i>Reporting</ion-item>

            <ion-item ui-sref="menu.FAQ" menu-close="" class="item-icon-left"><i class="icon ion-help calm"></i>FAQ</ion-item>

            <ion-item ui-sref="connexion" menu-close="" class="item-icon-left"><i class="icon ion-log-out"></i>Se deconnecter</ion-item>

        </ion-list>

    </ion-content>

</ion-side-menu>
```

And in the controller.js :

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
  .controller('homeCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    $rootScope.headerClass = 'bar-assertive';
  })

  .controller('reportingCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    $rootScope.headerClass = 'bar-balanced';
  })

  .controller('mediathequeCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    $rootScope.headerClass = 'bar-energized';
  })

  .controller('offreSFRCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    $rootScope.headerClass = 'bar-royal';
  })

  .controller('FAQCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    $rootScope.headerClass = 'bar-calm';
  })

  .controller('connexionCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  })
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change header  bar color of nav-bar on every page change

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location) {

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {

        if ($location.path() == '/menu/home') {
            $rootScope.headerClass = 'bar-assertive';
        } else if ($location.path() == '/menu/reporting') {
            $rootScope.headerClass = 'bar-balanced';
        } else if ($location.path() == '/menu/mediatheque') {
            $rootScope.headerClass = 'bar-energized';
        } else if ($location.path() == '/menu/offreSFR') {
            $rootScope.headerClass = 'bar-royal';
        } else if ($location.path() == '/menu/FAQ') {
            $rootScope.headerClass = 'bar-calm';
        }else{
           $rootScope.headerClass = 'bar-assertive';
        }
    });    

})
```

**[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/95iF9CiVa15YJU4XE5Rf?p=preview)**

**OR** you can add `ion-nav-bar` in every `view`

**menu.html**

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>        
        <ion-nav-view name="menu"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
            <div class="title">Menu</div>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content padding="false" class="side-menu-left has-header">
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item ui-sref="menu.home" menu-close="" class="item-icon-left" ng-click="reloadRoute()"><i class="icon ion-home assertive"></i>Persée</ion-item>
                <ion-item ui-sref="menu.offreSFR" menu-close="" class="item-icon-left" ng-click="reloadRoute()"><i class="icon ion-ios-cart royal"></i>Offres SFR</ion-item>
                <ion-item ui-sref="menu.mediatheque" menu-close="" class="item-icon-left" ng-click="reloadRoute()"><i class="icon ion-ios-book energized"></i>Mediatheque</ion-item>
                <ion-item ui-sref="menu.reporting" menu-close="" class="item-icon-left" ng-click="reloadRoute()"><i class="icon ion-stats-bars balanced"></i>Reporting</ion-item>
                <ion-item ui-sref="menu.FAQ" menu-close="" class="item-icon-left" ng-click="reloadRoute()"><i class="icon ion-help calm"></i>FAQ</ion-item>
                <ion-item ui-sref="connexion" menu-close="" class="item-icon-left bar-dark"><i class="icon ion-log-out"></i>Se deconnecter</ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-view title="Persée" cache-view="false">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header"></ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**repoerting.html**

```
<ion-view title="Reporting">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header"></ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**mediatheque.html**

```
<ion-view title="Mediatheque">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-energized">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header"></ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**offreSFR.html**

```
<ion-view title="Offre SFR" cache-view="false">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-royal">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header"></ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**FAQ.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="FAQ">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-calm">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header"></ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Thanks Ved, it works approximativly, i need to refresh the page to be ok, there is a event that allow this without refreshing by my own ?